# How to access context.xml parameter?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing an application and deploying it in Tomcat 7. I have defined some parameters in /etc/tomcat7/context.xml. How can I access them from my Java application?

context.xml

```xml
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Parameter name="my-param" value="my-string-value"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: From here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/512855/Tomcat/access-context-xml-parameter looks like you can read it directly by using `ServletContext#getInitParameter;`

Comment: Hi, I found the page. Unfortunately, I am unable to resolve method ' getServletContext()'.

Comment: If you are in a servlet then you can get the `ServletContext` by using `HttpServletRequest#getServletContext`

Comment: I am not in a servlet.

Comment: Can you show where do you want to retrieve this parameter or what's your specific scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I created ServletContextListener and got all I needed. Thank you for your help.

```
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {

    /**
     * Reads params from context.xml
     * @param event
     */
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
            String param = event.getServletContext().getInitParameter("my-param");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }
}
```